# Safe Wallet as smart contract deployer

Tags: gnosis-safe

We are currently working on a project and use a multisig wallet for deploying and then approve each modification that we will do on our smart contract on Arbitrum.

I think there are already a lot of example in regards of this use case but I don't find them. Could you please let me know if it is easely possible ?

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

I did this a year ago. Unfortunately the repo isn't public, but here are a few pointers which were valid at least back then:

- It's not easy
- You can use package `hardhat-safe-deployer`
- On top of that, you need to add some custom patches to packages `safe-core-sdk` and `safe-service-client` and `hardhat-safe-deployer`. The patches are mostly to add info about missing `chainId` to the deployment.

Maybe things have evolved since then and you can just import the package and that's it. Maybe not.

Answer (score 1):

To create(*deploy*) a contract via the multisig:

- Gnosis Safe has a Library for this - [CreateCall.sol](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/131f0d25135c1b98c185c940ae37fb0275ac4062/contracts/libraries/CreateCall.sol), deployed at [0x7cbB62EaA69F79e6873cD1ecB2392971036cFAa4](https://etherscan.io/address/0x7cbB62EaA69F79e6873cD1ecB2392971036cFAa4#code)
- The Contract has a method - `performCreate2`
- Call this method as normally you do via the multisig and pass the bytecode of the new contract to be deployed
- The transaction receipt will include the `ContractCreation` log, where you find the new address

A tx example (*random from etherscan*)

- Multisig normal `execTransaction` https://etherscan.io/tx/0x2837ba7d6cf39bc8f6fdff7e83b94c84e1b6b9351335300ec17d919a5eac9b99 which calls the `performCreate2` in `CreateCall`
- In [eventlog](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x2837ba7d6cf39bc8f6fdff7e83b94c84e1b6b9351335300ec17d919a5eac9b99#eventlog) you see the new contracts address.