# Is it possible to deploy a smart contract using multi-sig? i.e. contract will deploy only when multiple parties approve the tx?

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment

Is it possible to deploy smart contract using multi sig fetaure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is.

Two ways:

1. As @Sky mentioned, you can create a factory contract with a multisig functionality that includes manual checks for signatures. but this route is tricky and will need more time from your side.
2. You can use safe multisig wallets. You can create a factory contract that has multisig wallet as the owner and then call the deploy function via the transaction builder of the safe wallet. This would be much simpler and secure.

Comment: How we can  deploy contract using safe multisig wallet? i.e. i created a safe wallet, how can i deploy new contract using safe wallet?

Comment: You can check this post https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/145734/safe-wallet-as-smart-contract-deployer#:~:text=The%20Contract%20has%20a%20method,you%20find%20the%20new%20address

Comment: If you need a more detailed explanation, I can add it but only after 6 pm IST, a bit busy for the day.

Comment: Thank you @Zartaj Afser. I tried it was working.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but note that on **PUBLIC** blockchain, everyone can deploy a SmartContract (if they can afford it). So you can't stop people from deploying code that you don't approve.

For your use-case:
You can have your own smart-contract that deploys other contracts.
However, inside of this "deployer contract" you can implement mutli-sig functionality/checks. Making sure only whitelisted/group of address is allowed to do that.